# Access 2010 vba Array vs. Query

Tags: sql, arrays, vba, ms-access, vpn

I maintain an Access DB at work that we use to send out hourly updates on employee productivity.  Currently I have the form arranged into columns: The first column contains a ComboBox that we can select an employee's name from.  Once a name is selected, the next column fills in automatically with the agent's employee ID (TID), through this code:

```
        AgentName = rs.Fields("AgentName")

        sqlString2 = "SELECT * FROM " & "AllAgents WHERE FullName ='" & AgentName & "'"
        rs2.Open sqlString2, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

        AgentTID = rs2.Fields("TID").Value

        rs2.Close
```

Everything works fine when working in the office on the corporate network, but I've just discovered that working over the VPN causes horrendous slowdown when using this form. Slowness is an issue I've fought with over the VPN forever, but I had a thought in this case that may potentially aleve the slowness, I judt want to know if I'm correct before I go to the trouble of re-coding everything.

My idea is that I could create an array in VBA that would be populated with the agents' name & ID's when the form first loads, or even when the DB is opened on each inidividual laptop.  Then the DB would only need to read from the 'AllAgents' table once, and could simply use the array as a source instead.  What I doin't know is if this would have an effect or not.  Basically, if an Access DB is saved onto a network drive and accessed over a VPN, would the array be stored in the RAM of the laptop?  If it is, I would assume this would alleviate the speed issues and would be worthwhile taking the time to re-code.

Thanks,

Comment: How many rows in the AllAgents table?

Comment: Right now there are 163, but that changes on a fairly regular basis as we gain or lose agents

Answer (score 2):

The thing about form-level or global variables in Access is that you better have good error handling in the application. If an uncaptured error occurs it can result in those variables being for lack of better word discarded. The result would be the next time you try to access the data in the array you get another exception.

Here are a few things you could try before going the array route:

- Your combo box probably doesn't need to be bound to your recordset `rs` directly. Set the source of the combo box at design time to the underlying query or table.
- This makes it possible to simply refer to the combo box's bound field using something like this: `AgentName = cboAgentName.Value`

(If you can eliminate an unnecessary recordset object from the form the better off you will be in the long run)

- Your lookup code shouldn't need to use `SELECT *`. This just isn't a good practice to use in production code. Instead, use `SELECT TID`. Basically, only return in your query the fields you actually need.
- You don't need to use the `adOpenKeySet` option, which is unnecessary overhead. You should be able to use `adOpenForwardOnly`.

I would also suggest looking at the AllAgents table to make sure that there is an index on the field you are using for the lookup. If there isn't, think about adding one.

You still might need to go the array route, but these are relatively simple things that you can use to try to troubleshoot performance without introducing massive code changes to the application.

Comment: I went through and tried what I could form your suggestions, and I just have a couple questions if you don't mind.  First, you suggest setting the source of the ComboBox at design time;  how is this accomplished?  (The second point I removed, it was a matter of the agent's name not being spelled correctly :).)

Comment: @KevenM take a look at this article which outlines how to set the source at design time http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-list-box-combo-box-or-drop-down-list-box-HP005240581.aspx